# Mysql select with CASE not retrieving other column value?

Tags: mysql, sql

As the answer that I got receive from my question which drive me nuts applying to my code for some reason, why it did not worked.

Here's a part of my data on table.

[image]

**Original Code:**

```
SELECT AGE_RANGE, COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT CASE
        WHEN YearsOld BETWEEN 0 AND 5 THEN '0-5'
        WHEN YearsOld BETWEEN 6 AND 10 THEN '6-10'
        WHEN YearsOld BETWEEN 11 AND 15 THEN '11-15'
        WHEN YearsOld BETWEEN 16 AND 20 THEN '16-20'
        WHEN YearsOld BETWEEN 21 AND 30 THEN '21-30'
        WHEN YearsOld BETWEEN 31 AND 40 THEN '31-40'
        WHEN YearsOld > 40 THEN '40+'
        END AS 'AGE_RANGE'
        FROM (
            SELECT YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(DATE(birthdate)) 'YearsOld' 
            FROM MyTable
        ) B
) A
GROUP BY AGE_RANGE
```

and here is the result.

[image]

What I'm trying to do is, I'm trying to add another column which would count on how many people who is in that area which would be **location** as you would see on the picture on top which includes Perth, Western Australia, Sunbury, Victoria and so on.

**First attempt to fix my problem**

As you would see below, I've added location, and COUNT(location) loc to get the name of the location and count on how many location that is duplicated in the table.

```
SELECT AGE_RANGE, COUNT(*), location, COUNT(location) loc FROM (
    SELECT CASE
        WHEN YearsOld BETWEEN 0 AND 5 THEN '0-5'
        WHEN YearsOld BETWEEN 6 AND 10 THEN '6-10'
        WHEN YearsOld BETWEEN 11 AND 15 THEN '11-15'
        WHEN YearsOld BETWEEN 16 AND 20 THEN '16-20'
        WHEN YearsOld BETWEEN 21 AND 30 THEN '21-30'
        WHEN YearsOld BETWEEN 31 AND 40 THEN '31-40'
        WHEN YearsOld > 40 THEN '40+'
        END AS 'AGE_RANGE', 'location'
        FROM (
            SELECT YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(DATE(birthday)) 'YearsOld' 
            FROM event_participants
        ) B
) A
FROM event_participants WHERE location <> '' GROUP BY location HAVING loc >= 1 ORDER BY loc DESC LIMIT 5
```

Which results to..

[image]

Obviously, hearing from the aid of god doesn't work out to well..

**My second attempt to fix this problem**

```
SELECT AGE_RANGE, COUNT(*), location FROM (
    SELECT CASE
        WHEN YearsOld BETWEEN 0 AND 5 THEN '0-5'
        WHEN YearsOld BETWEEN 6 AND 10 THEN '6-10'
        WHEN YearsOld BETWEEN 11 AND 15 THEN '11-15'
        WHEN YearsOld BETWEEN 16 AND 20 THEN '16-20'
        WHEN YearsOld BETWEEN 21 AND 30 THEN '21-30'
        WHEN YearsOld BETWEEN 31 AND 40 THEN '31-40'
        WHEN YearsOld > 40 THEN '40+'
        END AS 'AGE_RANGE', 'location'
        FROM (
            SELECT YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(DATE(birthday)) 'YearsOld' 
            FROM event_participants
        ) B
) A
GROUP BY AGE_RANGE
```

And the result is...

[image]

Instead of **showing** the name of the countries, it only show location.

Well..

Long story short, what's wrong with the code? Any solution for this stuff?

It was like, my desired result would be,

```
AGE_RANGE COUNT(*) location            total number of same location

16-20        4     Name of location                 #

21-30       45     Name of location                 #

31-40       79     Name of location                 #

40+        102     Name of location                 #
```

Comment: Please use SQL fiddle :)

Comment: if `location` is a column, don't wrap it with single quote, `AS 'AGE_RANGE', location` << remove it and see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work: Think of each subquery as it's own table, so you just need to make sure to select all the columns you need. (CASE WHEN THEN END AS) is actually just a single column value. You will probably also want to group on location so you can get the same age ranges for different locations. (Ex. 11-15 in Canada and 11-15 in USA)

```
SELECT AGE_RANGE, COUNT(*), A.location FROM (
        SELECT CASE
            WHEN YearsOld BETWEEN 0 AND 5 THEN '0-5'
            WHEN YearsOld BETWEEN 6 AND 10 THEN '6-10'
            WHEN YearsOld BETWEEN 11 AND 15 THEN '11-15'
            WHEN YearsOld BETWEEN 16 AND 20 THEN '16-20'
            WHEN YearsOld BETWEEN 21 AND 30 THEN '21-30'
            WHEN YearsOld BETWEEN 31 AND 40 THEN '31-40'
            WHEN YearsOld > 40 THEN '40+'
            END AS 'AGE_RANGE', B.location
            FROM (
                SELECT YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(DATE(birthday)) 'YearsOld',
                location /* << just missing this select */
                FROM event_participants
            ) B
    ) A
    GROUP BY A.location, AGE_RANGE
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't know how to say this but, I did what you exactly said on my past attempt before posting this question, debugging here debugging there till I get crazy enough to post again. Well, for some reason, the value of location COLUMN, is "location" not the name of the country.
The first three column names on the picture on the very top is "gender" "birthday" "location"
It matches the location column on the code, yet it only shows the result 'location'.

Comment: Slightly modified the code, you may need to use B.location instead of 'location' in the A subquery. Also be sure you add the location column to the select of the B subquery.

Comment: Ohhh! It worked! Though, it was different result as I was expecting though. Still, I got all the requirements I need, was able to show all the values with corresponding ages, I can manage this on my own now. Once again, thanks for helping me again! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT AGE_RANGE, COUNT(*), location FROM (
        SELECT CASE
            WHEN YearsOld BETWEEN 0 AND 5 THEN '0-5'
            WHEN YearsOld BETWEEN 6 AND 10 THEN '6-10'
            WHEN YearsOld BETWEEN 11 AND 15 THEN '11-15'
            WHEN YearsOld BETWEEN 16 AND 20 THEN '16-20'
            WHEN YearsOld BETWEEN 21 AND 30 THEN '21-30'
            WHEN YearsOld BETWEEN 31 AND 40 THEN '31-40'
            WHEN YearsOld > 40 THEN '40+'
            END AS 'AGE_RANGE', 'location'
            FROM (
                SELECT YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(DATE(birthday)) 'YearsOld'
                FROM event_participants
            ) B
    ) A
    GROUP BY location, AGE_RANGE
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not correct:-

```
SELECT AGE_RANGE, COUNT(*), location FROM
```

When you use `GROUP BY` the attribute list in select must be applied either to aggregate function or must be a part of `GROUP BY` clause.

In the example below you cannot show the name of the location as the person in the `age-group` may belong to different location:-

```
AGE_RANGE COUNT(*) location            total number of same location

16-20        4     Name of location                 #

21-30       45     Name of location                 #
```